# Boolean Simplification - Confused

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, boolean

I am doing some mathematics, and I am currently stuck on something. I do not understand this part at all, how can one approach this?

No variable is used here.

**Problem:**

Simplify the following Boolean expressions as far as possible, using and stating which Boolean laws and axioms you use at every step.

$$(x+xy)'y'+x'$$

I simply have no idea how to approach this, and what is the best way to remember the steps in terms of approaching this problem and simplifying as far as possible.

---

1. $(x+xy)'y'+x'$
2. $(x' \cdot (xy)')y'+x'$ (First deMorgan law)
3. $(x' + (x' + y'))y'+x'$ (Second deMorgan law)
4. $(x'x' + x'y')y'+x'$ (Distributive law)

**EDIT:** This is how far I am getting, and I am still somehow overwhelmed and confused.

Comment: Start by simplifying $x + xy$. If you can do that, you should be able to manage the rest as well.

Comment: @ummg, please see my latest attempt.

Comment: DeMorgan's laws are not the way to go here. I don't know exactly which boolean laws you have proven in your course, but take a look at the absorption laws [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws).

Comment: The second one should read $x + xy = x$ in your notation. I suggest you also think about why this must be true. Maybe draw up a truth table.

Comment: @ummg, we use the following book in the course: *Discrete Mathematics for Computing, 3rd Edition by Peter Grossman*

Comment: @ummg, Why would I use the **absorption laws** here? I don't get it. My first instinct was to use the **Identity laws**. But, then, I looked over something and saw something of similar fashion and thought, maybe it is applicable here. The final answer turns out to be: $x'$ according to the solution paper.

Comment: Why use absorption laws? Because it works. However, there are other ways to arrive at the same result. Indeed the relevant absorption law itself can be proven by using identity, annihilation, and distribution laws: $x + xy = x \cdot 1 + x \cdot y = x(1 + y) = x \cdot 1 = x$. And yes, the final answer is indeed $x'$.

Comment: @ummg, So your approach appears faster and simpler, can you explain this, maybe as your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are surely many ways to simplify the expression
$$(x + xy)'y' + x'.$$
One is to use the absorption law $x + xy = x$ twice (along with commutativity, i suppose) to arrive at
$$(x + xy)'y' + x' = x'.$$
If you have not yet proven this law in your course, you can do so by using more elementary laws, say by an argument like
$$x + xy = x \cdot 1 + x \cdot y = x(1 + y) = x \cdot 1 = x,$$
or by making a truth table.

Comment: Can you show the steps and laws applied to arrive to the solution of simplification?

Comment: I'm sure you can fill in the missing steps yourself.

Comment: Wrong. Sorry, your answer is wrong.

Comment: I very much doubt that. But sure, what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @AlixBlaine This is correct. Apply absorption $x+xy=x$ to obtain the expression $x'y'+x'$, and apply it again to obtain $x'$. No need for more laws!